# How to specify a connection string on a WCF project that uses Entity Framework code first?

Tags: wcf, entity-framework-4.1

Considering a Visual Studio 2010 solution with:

- A class library containing code-first Entity Framework 4.1 entities and DbContext;
- A default WCF project that references the entities class library:

How should the connection string for a remote SQL Server database be specified in the WCF project so that Entity Framework 4.1 will be able to access this database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the connection string to the web.config of the WCF project.

It doesn't matter that the EF is declared in a referencing assembly. The configuration is always loaded from the current process, which in this case is the WCF project.